# Bad Alignment with bordermatrix in mathjax

Tags: mathjax, bordermatrix

I'm trying to make a border matrix but the elements outside the pmatrix are badalignment respect the pmatrix using Mathjax. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{fancy} %seleccionamos un estilo
\lhead{1º BACHILLER-HUM} %texto izquierda de la cabecera
\chead{I.E.S. OLEANA} %texto centro de la cabecera
\rfoot{I.E.S. OLEANA} %texto izquierda del pie
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\pagenumbering{gobble} %quitamos el número de página
\begin{document}
   $$
    \begin{array}{c c} &
    \begin{array}{cccc} \color{red}{98} & \color{red}{99} & \color{red}{00} & \color{red}{01} \\
    \end{array}
    \\
    \begin{array}{c c c c}
    \color{red}{F_1} \\
    \color{red}{F_2}\\
    \color{red}{F_3}
    \end{array}
    &
    \begin{pmatrix}
    278\;450 & 284\;220 & 298\;280 & 311\;600 \\
    353\;525 & 359\;650 & 378\;295 & 393\;900 \\
    125\;900 & 127\;610 & 133\;320 & 139\;000
    \end{pmatrix}
    \end{array}
  $$
 \end{document}
```

I want red rows and columns are alignmented respect the proper matrix.
Thanks.

Comment: note that mathjax formatting is off topic here, it would be easier to test in latex if you made the example into a complete document

Comment: The posted document produces `! Missing $ inserted` as `array` has to be in math mode.

Comment: Added and fixed, sorry so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pad the first array to ensure the columns match the second array.

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{fancy} %seleccionamos un estilo
\lhead{1º BACHILLER-HUM} %texto izquierda de la cabecera
\chead{I.E.S. OLEANA} %texto centro de la cabecera
\rfoot{I.E.S. OLEANA} %texto izquierda del pie
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\pagenumbering{gobble} %quitamos el número de página
\begin{document}
   \[
    \begin{array}{c c} &
    \begin{array}{cccc} \color{red}{98} & \color{red}{99} & \color{red}{00} & \color{red}{01} \\
     \phantom{111;111}&\phantom{111;111}&\phantom{111;111}&\phantom{111;111}
    \end{array}
    \\[-10pt]
    \begin{array}{c c c c}
    \color{red}{F_1} \\
    \color{red}{F_2}\\
    \color{red}{F_3}
    \end{array}
    &
    \begin{pmatrix}
    278\;450 & 284\;220 & 298\;280 & 311\;600 \\
    353\;525 & 359\;650 & 378\;295 & 393\;900 \\
    125\;900 & 127\;610 & 133\;320 & 139\;000
    \end{pmatrix}
    \end{array}
  \]
 \end{document}
```

Comment: I thought I'd insert an answer using the nicematrix package. I don't know, since MathJaX is off-topic here if you can enter my answer. However +1.